# Setting up custom certificate authentication in IIS 10 using OWIN

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, iis-10

We are trying to setup multiple authentication using OWIN/Katana and the webapi will be hosted on IIS 10 with certificate authentication and windows authentication. I'm following this [blog by Andras Nemes](https://dotnetcodr.com/2016/01/28/using-client-certificates-in-net-part-6-setting-up-client-certificates-for-local-test-usage/comment-page-1/#comment-87166) to setup my local client and server certificate authentication. Unfortunately, after setting up the Web API in IIS, when I try to access the website with the client certificate, I'm getting 403 Forbidden error which says that the certificate is not trusted or invalid. I'm not sure what is causing this issue.
I tried setting up my IIS by following other posts also, I've tried to [add the website certificate to IIS and bind it with mylocalsite.local](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2016/08/22/how-to-create-an-iis-website-that-requires-client-certificate-using-self-signed-certificates/) and tried with and without editing “system.webServer/security/authentication/iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication”.

After searching a lot I found similar results but none of them worked. I'm not sure if it is because of the IIS 10 has a different workflow of configuring client server certificate authentication mechanism or is there a problem with my certificates.

Following are my self signed certificates, and I also have there pfx files.
**RootCertificate:**
[image: RootCertificate]
RootCertificate.cer has been installed in Local Computer Trusted Root Certification Authorities as well as in Current User Trusted certificates.

**localtestclientcert:**
[image: localtestclientcert.cer]
[image: localtestclientcert certificateion path]
localtestclientcert.pfx has been installed in Current User under Personal certificates.

**mylocalsite.local:**
[image: mylocalsite.local.cer]
[image: mylocalsite.local.cer certification path]
mylocalsite.local.pfx has been installed in Local Computer under personal certificates.

**IIS Server certificates**
[image: server certificates]

**website bindings**
[image: website bindings]

**SSL settings of the website**
[image: SSL settings]

**EDIT 1:** Modified "Trusted Certificates" to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" for clarity

Comment: This is not a programming question, hence it's completely off topic here. However, try to install the certificate under the Root Certificates (or similar, can't remember the name) since it's self-signed

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Camilo Terevinto. I thought this is the best place to ask this question as many developers might have encountered the same issue.
But i've installed the certificate in Trusted Root Certification Authorities only. I'll edit and update in the question.

Comment: Not a surprise that "many developers might have encountered the same issue", because they are usually not the right people to configure certificates and lack of the proper knowledge. That's why @CamiloTerevinto suggested off-topic and sites like ServerFault might be better places. In short when you said "we" you should ensure that an expert like your domain administrator should be involved. He/she must fully understand the related concepts in order to manage a domain.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the root certificate to the trusted authorities using MMC (machine account) as indicated in this tutorial
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/asiatech/how-to-create-an-iis-website-that-requires-client-certificate-using-self-signed-certificates

If you import the certif to perosnal account using certmgr you'll get this error

Comment: While you referred to a very good article written by my friend, you should also notice that the questioner has configured what you suggested, because otherwise "Certificate path" in the screen shots should show errors. Thus, your answer might not be that helpful when the actual cause is not clear.